# Split oracle column value into comma separated values

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table with column having value 5 in oracle
I want to change the value of column to array of values like [5,4,3,2,1]
means values with difference of 1

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to change the value of column"? Do you want to modify ("UPDATE") the existing table, by changing the value in the column? Do you want to change the value from a single number, 5, to an array of values? That is not possible - a column can have only one data type in a database. (It is very likely that's not what you really want, I am only trying to illustrate that the specific words you chose to describe your problem make no sense.)

Comment: I am not trying to update the existing table.I just want select query that gives output:[5,4,3,2,1].

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct application of "hierarchical queries" (see the Oracle documentation if not familiar). It uses `sys_connect_by_path` to create the list of values (the square brackets are added outside the hierarchical query - and the leading comma, which `sys_connect_by_path` generates, needs to be chopped off first, with `ltrim()`).

```
with
     test_data ( id, val ) as (
       select 101, 5 from dual union all
       select 103, 3 from dual
     )
-- End of made-up test data; NOT part of the query.
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Change table and column names as needed.
select id, val,
       '[' || ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(val - level + 1, ','), ',') || ']' as val_list
from   test_data
where  connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by level <= val
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

 ID  VAL  VAL_LIST
---  ---  -----------
101    5  [5,4,3,2,1]
103    3  [3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way is create function for that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION toArray (p_value NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR
AS
   l_result   VARCHAR (4000) := '[';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN REVERSE 2 .. p_value
   LOOP
      l_result := l_result || i || ',';
   END LOOP;

   IF (p_value >= 1)
   THEN
      l_result := l_result || 1;
   END IF;

   l_result := l_result || ']';
   RETURN l_result;
END;
```

Query `select toArray(5) from dual` 
return result 
`[5,4,3,2,1]`

Comment: If you work with databases, create functions (or any other kind of PL/SQL code) only when the "problem at hand" can't be solved with plain SQL (or when the plain SQL solution would be too complicated, difficult to maintain etc.) No need for functions to solve *this* problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bit simpler approach to use. Hope below snippet helps.
Only drawback here what i can suggest is LISTAGG works only oracle version 11 and above. So it wont work in below versions.

```
SELECT listagg(a.lvl, ',') within GROUP (
ORDER BY a.lvl DESC) somedata
from
  (SELECT '&Enter_val'+1 - level lvl,
    1 lvl2
  from dual
    CONNECT BY level < '&Enter_val'+1
  ORDER BY lvl DESC
  )a;
```